# Office 2007/2003 VSTO Shared Add-In Design Query

Tags: vb.net, ms-office, vsto, add-in

I am designing a shared add-in using VB.Net 2008 and VSTO that has to fire up when any MS Office App is started. It has to work for both 2002, 2003 and 2007 applications. I have managed to put together a working add-in that pops up a test message stating the version of Office and the Application name and tested this across all the apps ok.

The next part of the solution is to code the application specific code that needs to run for document auditing and corporate protective marking as well as, for example; in Excel checking that all the Add-Ins are linked to the Network Add-Ins folder.

My approach from now was going to be to late bind against the application object and set one of my typed (e.g. Excel) application object references which exist in the code to this object.

I'm still relativly new to VSTO so if I am doing something odd please can you let me know! :)

Ta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have completed this project and did it the way I specified using late bindig. It works lieka dream for all office apps both XP and 2007. :) I feel like I am announcing this to myself though as I didn't recieve a single answer or comment. Maybe you should have sexed up the title a bit Mas. Yeah maybe I should.

Comment: :) 
at least/last you have received a smiley.